# Magento2 - How to created cart with product and quantity and billing address and after that assign to any customer?

Tags: magento2

Magento2 - I want to create cart from frontside or backend by specify product and its quantity and adding shipping and billing address to cart.
And after I create specific link for customer and send that link to customer so when that customer open that link then that cart assign to that customer, so that customer only have to do payment only.

Comment: you have trie so far?

Comment: I tried but no luck, I not getting relation for guest visitor id and quote id.